# Defining bits in Freertos

Tags: bit-manipulation, freertos

I run the simple FreeRTOS code, in which program wait for five seconds for MYTASK_Bit to clear, and then ‎create a task “vMyTask”, which execute printf repeatedly with delay of one seconds.

The program runs fine ‎and do what it is supposed to do.‎

I have two questions:‎

‎1.‎    I have set MYTASK_Bit, which is first bit, ‎to 1 (‎#define MYTASK_Bit (1 << 0)‎).
Does'nt this means ‎that the program should find it as "SET" (as its value is 1) and not wait for five seconds? ‎

‎2.‎    If I set MYTASK_Bit to 0 (‎#define MYTASK_Bit (0 << 0)), I get the error :‎
‎ assert failed: xEventGroupWaitBits event_groups.c:371 (uxBitsToWaitFor != 0)‎.‎
What does it means?‎
My code is as below:‎

```
    ‎#define MYTASK_Bit (1 << 0)‎
    EventGroupHandle_t  xMyEventGroup; ‎

void vMyTask()‎
‎{‎
‎    for (;;){‎
‎        printf("This is in vMyTask.\n”);‎
‎       vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);‎
       ‎}‎
‎}
‎
void app_main(void)‎
‎{‎
‎    xMyEventGroup = xEventGroupCreate();‎
‎    xEventGroupWaitBits(xMyEventGroup, MYTASK_Bit, pdTRUE, pdFALSE, 5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);‎
‎    printf("Starting vMyTask\n");‎
‎    xTaskCreate(&vMyTask, "vMyTask", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL);‎}‎
‎}‎
```

I am using ESP32 board with esp_idf.

Comment: See API doc https://www.freertos.org/xEventGroupWaitBits.html

Comment: I have already gone through it but it does not answer my question.

Comment: ‘uxBitsToWaitFor must not be set to 0.’ ?